# telerik report with large number of controls not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, telerik, telerik-reporting

I have a report with planty of controls(like panels, textboxes, picture boxes and expressions too) i.e. around 5000 controls. When I am trying to render the report in PDF (from asp.Net application) it is working in debug mode whereas not working after deploying it to IIS server, it is taking time to complete the InitializeComponent method. Can anyone have the similar problem? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The report was not rendering since the design file of the report is larger than allowed by IIS. Refer the link http://www.telerik.com/forums/stackoverflow-exception-when-creating-telerik-report-with-large-designer-filesize-on-iis-7. So the issue resolved by spliiting the report into sub reports which worked like a charm.